# React Native Navigation does not exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I had to take a break from working on my react native app for a couple of months and when i came back to work on it again i couldn't boot anything up and i am getting a load of React Native Navigation errors... 
I dont really know where to start with this, i have made some changes to the java files but nothing seems to get me out of this hole... 
 the error is below... if anyone knows how to deal with this i would be really greatful

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>   Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainActivity.java:3: error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist
>   import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
>                                   ^
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainActivity.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>   public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
>                                     ^
>     symbol: class NavigationActivity
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainApplication.java:21: error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist
>   import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
>                                   ^
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainApplication.java:22: error: package com.reactnativenavigation.react does not exist
>   import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
>                                         ^
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainApplication.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>   public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
>                                        ^
>     symbol: class NavigationApplication
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
>     new NavigationReactNativeHost(this) {
>         ^
>     symbol:   class NavigationReactNativeHost
>     location: class MainApplication
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainApplication.java:47: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>     @Override
>     ^
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainApplication.java:51: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>     @Override
>     ^
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainApplication.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
>       super.onCreate();
>       ^
>     symbol:   variable super
>     location: class MainApplication
>   C:\git\BattleBuddy\android\app\src\main\java\com\battlebuddy\MainApplication.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
>       initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
>       ^
>     symbol:   method initializeFlipper(MainApplication,ReactInstanceManager)
>     location: class MainApplication

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

This is from the build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        RNNKotlinVersion = "1.3.61" // Or any version above 1.3.x
        RNNKotlinStdlib = "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        // ADD THIS
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61"
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

this if from the app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
}
```

This is the mainapp

```
public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
  new NavigationReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean isDebug() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }
    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };
  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }
```

main activigty just looks like this

```
package com.battlebuddy;

import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;

public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
}
```

If there is anything  you can think of that would help a lot

Comment: Can you post the changes you made to the java files?

Comment: This question looks like it has answers on Google. Have you tried looking at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27443 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17197 ?

Comment: I updated the post with the new info you asked for